# Different result displaying LM35's temperature on a 4-digit 7-segment using PIC16F877A versus Arduino

Tags: arduino, adc, pic, temperature, lm35

I'm working on a project using a display [LM35](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf?ts=1697565223453&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM35%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DLM35%2526ds_k%253Dlm35%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQjw4bipBhCyARIsAFsieCwz9ubYlfXgRsazNvo_biKxJ296MZZIOYlcaZ3ufTCsF_9MXy38G_caAnu_EALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) using [PIC16F877A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/39582C.pdf) but the room temp was measured around 70°C. I tried using this LM35 with Arduino and it showed result around 40°C. I used a multimeter to measure the voltage at Vout of the LM35 and it showed 0.67 for while using the PIC and 0.15 while using the Arduino. I connected the Vcc and GND of the sensor to the 5V pin and GND pin on the Arduino board in both case. I wonder: Why is there a big difference while using these two microcontrollers?

This is the code i used for the PIC and it worked fine while simulating on Proteus(I'm using CCS compiler):

```
#include <YO.h>
unsigned int8 MaLed[] = {0xC0,0xF9,0xA4,0xB0,0x99,0x92,0x82,0xF8,0x80,0x98};
void docADC()
{
   setup_ADC(ADC_clock_internal);
   setup_ADC_ports(AN0);
   set_ADC_channel(0);
   delay_us(100);
}
unsigned int16 chuc,donvi,x;
void hienthi(unsigned int16 x)
{
   chuc=x/10;
   donvi=x%10;
   
   output_d(MaLed[chuc]);
   output_high(pin_C0);
   delay_us(100);
   output_low(pin_C0);
   
   output_d(MaLed[donvi]);
   output_high(pin_C1);
   delay_us(100);
   output_low(pin_C1);
   
  
   
   output_d(0x9c);
   output_high(pin_C2);
   delay_us(100);
   output_low(pin_C2);
   
   
   
   output_d(0xC6);
   output_high(pin_C3);
   delay_us(100);
   output_low(pin_C3);
}

void main()

{
   SET_TRIS_D(0X00);
   SET_TRIS_C(0X00);

   while(TRUE){
   
     hienthi(x);
     docADC();
     x = read_ADC() * 0.488 ;
      
    
   }}
```

This is the code for Arduino:

```
int sensorPin = A0;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}
 
void loop() {
 
 int reading = analogRead(sensorPin);  
 
 float voltage = reading * 5.0 / 1024.0; 
 
 float temp = voltage * 100.0;
 
 Serial.println(temp);
 
 delay(1000);
}
```

This is the schematic:
[image]
[image]
This is my board:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a schematic of your circuit? Pictures of the board are also useful.

Comment: It depends how you connected them up and what software you wrote. We don't know what you made different unless you show how things were wired and what code was running. Please describe in more detail to find if the error is in hardware connections or code.

Comment: I added more details in my question. Thank for your reply @Justme

Comment: 0.15V mean 15°C, looks realistic. Neither 40°C or 70°C is your ambient temperature, I hope.

Comment: The source of the PIC has no `read_ADC()`. Please add it. And while you're [edit]ing it, format your source consistently.

Comment: Can you explain clearer a bit?. I just started get into PIC so there's a lot of thing i don't know @thebusybee

Comment: What is not clear? -- Your source calls `read_ADC()` but you don't show that code. -- And the data sheet of the LM35 says 10mV/°C and you measure 150mV, so it's 15°C. Remember your primary school math. -- And you know what "formatting the source" means, don't you?

Comment: That's a function in the 16F877A.h library and I used it to read the Vout of the LM35